# How to make the cell turn into red and green colour based on the value?

Tags: php

[image]

How to make the cell turn into red and green colour based on the value? I want the cell value changed colour like in the image above.

```
$data = array();
while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query) ) {  // preparing an array
$nestedData=array(); 


$nestedData[] = $row["no"];
$nestedData[] = $row["svcno"];
$nestedData[] = $row["pangkat"];
$nestedData[] = $row["name"];
$nestedData[] = $row["year"];
$nestedData[] = $row["system"];
$nestedData[] = $row["course"];
$nestedData[] = $row["f1"];
$nestedData[] = $row["f2"];

$data[] = $nestedData;
}

$json_data = array(
        "draw"            => intval( $requestData['draw'] ),   // for every 
request/draw by clientside , they send a number as a parameter, when they 
recieve a response/data they first check the draw number, so we are sending 
same number in draw. 
        "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalData ),  // total number of 
records
        "recordsFiltered" => intval( $totalFiltered ), // total number of 
records after searching, if there is no searching then totalFiltered = 
totalData
        "data"            => $data   // total data array
        );

echo json_encode($json_data);  // send data as json format

 ?>
```

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that has cells.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to change the color of your values like you want by dynamically changing the background color property of the td tag in a table.  You should be able to study this and adapt it to your code.

```
$array = array(1,4,3,7,8,3,5,7,1,8,1,5,6);

echo
'<table>' .
  '<tr>' .
    '<th>Value</th>' .
  '</tr>';

foreach($array as $key){

  if($key <= 3){
   $color = 'green';
  }elseif($key > 3 && $key <= 6){
    $color = 'yellow';
   }elseif($key > 6 && $key <= 10){
      $color = 'red';
    }

  echo
  '<tr>' .
    '<td style="background-color:' . $color . ';">' . $key . '</td>' .
  '</tr>';

}

echo
'</table>';
```

Comment: i do not know how to insert the code into my coding. may you show the full coding ?

Comment: My code is just an example.  You are going to have to figure out how to make it work with your code.  I suggest that you do some reading or watch some youtube tutorials on the basics of how to code php and html.  Your goal is to take your data as an array and run it through a loop and have it dynamically generate your table for you.

Comment: i have try it but it do not function. maybe i make mistake when inserting the code. may you show me the full code please?