# How do I give a div a random background color from an array

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I want to give my div a random background color, I have a array of 
( ['red','green','blue','#f00'] ) colors that i'd like to have as my div background color but I don't know a way to display them randomly inside my div  on every time this div render?

Comment: randomly on click or what ?

Comment: What's mean by 6 options?

Comment: This addresses your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50207574/how-to-make-the-cell-turn-into-red-and-green-colour-based-on-the-value/50207785#50207785

Answer (score 3):

Using javascript `rand()` function you can it without jQuery too.

```js
getNewRandomColor();

function getNewRandomColor()
{
    var myArray = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];    
    var rand = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.backgroundColor = rand;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">Something here</div>


<button onclick="getNewRandomColor()">Get New Random Color</button>
```

You can also apply more colors to array to get more random color.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample code which changes the color of div on each page load

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  var colors = ['red','blue','green','yellow','cyan','orange'];
  var new_color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
  $('#color-div').css('background-color',new_color);
});
```

What it does is that from the array using `Math` function a random colour is selected and is applied to the div

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p801jcur/6/) here

Answer (score 0):

Using `background-color` and plain JS to change the `style.backgroundColor` property:

```js
const COLORS = [
  'red',
  'green',
  'blue',
  'yellow',
  'cyan',
  'black',
];

document.onclick = () => {  
  document.body.style.backgroundColor
    = COLORS[Math.floor(Math.random() * COLORS.length)];
};
```

Same, but using CSS variables:

```js
const COLORS = [
  'red',
  'green',
  'blue',
  'yellow',
  'cyan',
  'black',
];

document.onclick = () => {
  document.body.style.setProperty('--bg', COLORS[Math.floor(Math.random() * COLORS.length)]);
};
```

```css
:root {
  --bg: white;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--bg);
}
```